# Media keys won't work unless certain programs are selected

Tags: keyboard, windows-8.1, services, media-keys, hid

I just bought a Corsair Vengeance K70 which comes with four media keys: stop, skip (forward and backward), and play/pause. The problem is they don't work. I can only use them when either the Services window (through Computer Management, Task Manager, or `services.msc`, Curse Voice, Logitech Gaming Software, or Gigabyte Force is open and the selected window.

My HID Service is set to *Automatic (Trigger Start)* and is running. Media keys also don't work when the HID service is disabled.

I've tried closing all open programs as well as unplugging all extra hardware, none of which helps. I've also tried different USB ports.

This is also after a fresh install of Windows 7. Any ideas?

Programs confirmed to work:

- Ccleaner
- Computer Management
- Gigabtye Force
- Logitech Gaming Software
- MSI Installers
- Services
- Task Manager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the Google Music Chrome extension was the cause of this.

Case closed.

Comment: Indeed. Go to Settings -> Extensions and then disable Google Play Music

Comment: I've been looking all over the place for the cause of this frustrating problem - Google Play Music was also the source.  Thank you!

Comment: I have this issue as well, but I don't have Google Music Chrome extension installed. Any ideas?

Comment: @MarcusEkwall Best bet would be to start closing programs one at a time and testing between. Once you find the program that's hijacking your media keys, it's easier from there.

Comment: @DarkWolffe I figured it out! The Plex extension had its "Keyboard shortcuts" set to `Global`. Setting them to `In Chrome` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was some other google extensions in the chrome browser. Disabled them until it worked.  Had to close and re-open chrome each time to test.